# How to add a option for tree view values which comes from db

Tags: asp.net

[image: I have multiple tree views which gives the values from database now for these values there should be a Select All option which will select/unselect all the values under the tree view]

I have multiple tree views which gives the values from database now for these values there should be a Select All option which will select/unselect all the values under the tree view

Below is the table structure in my db

| ID | Name | Type | SubType | Type |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 4 | Child Value 1 | 6 | tv1 |  |
| 5 | Child Value 2 | 6 | tv1 |  |
| 6 | Child Value 21 | 7 | tv2 |  |
| 7 | Child Value 22 | 7 | tv2 |  |
| 8 | Child Value 23 | 7 | tv2 |  |
| 9 | Child Value 31 | 1 | tv3 | IB |
| 10 | Child Value 32 | 1 | tv3 |  |
| 11 | Child Value 33 | 1 | tv3 | IB |

```
<Items>
                                        <ext:DisplayField runat="server" FieldLabel="<%$ Resources: MMR,RToP%>" ID="lRP" LabelWidth="130" LabelAlign="Left"></ext:DisplayField>
                                        <ext:Panel runat="server" Flex="25" Title="<%$ Resources: MMR,P%>" MarginSpec="0 5 5 0" Layout="FitLayout" TitleAlign="Center" Border="false">
                                            <Items>
                                                <ext:MultiSelect runat="server" ID="msP" MultiSelect="true" Height="100" Scrollable="Vertical" AutoScroll="true" DisplayField="Name" ValueField="ID" ShowCheckbox="false" SingleSelect="true" StoreID="stP">
                                                </ext:MultiSelect>
                                                <ext:GridPanel ID="grdP" runat="server" Border="true" TitleAlign="Center" AutoHeight="true" Hidden="true" StoreID="stProducts" Frame="false" AutoScroll="true" MarginSpec="10 0 0 0" OverflowY="Scroll">
                                                    <ColumnModel ID="ColumnModel1" runat="server">
                                                        <Columns>
                                                            <ext:Column ID="colName" runat="server" Text="<%$ Resources: MMR,Name%>" DataIndex="Name" Flex="1">
                                                            </ext:Column>
                                                        </Columns>
                                                    </ColumnModel>
                                                    <SelectionModel>
                                                        <ext:CheckboxSelectionModel runat="server" ID="chkRP" Mode="Simple" ShowHeaderCheckbox="true">
                                                        </ext:CheckboxSelectionModel>
                                                    </SelectionModel>
                                                    <View>
                                                        <ext:GridView ID="gvP" runat="server" TrackOver="false" />
                                                    </View>
                                                    <Features>
                                                        <ext:GroupingSummary runat="server" EnableNoGroups="true" HideGroupedHeader="true" EnableGroupingMenu="false" StartCollapsed="true"
                                                            GroupHeaderTplString='<div style=\"font-weight:bold;\">{name}</div>'>
                                                        </ext:GroupingSummary>
                                                    </Features>
                                                </ext:GridPanel>
                                            </Items>
                                        </ext:Panel>
                                    </Items>
```